# How to send email in SharePoint 2010 event handler solution?

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

I am creating a C# event handler for SharePoint 2010 (sandboxed solution). When the ItemAdded event is hit, I have some logic that I perform, and then I would like to send an email.

Unfortunately, it appears that SPUtility.SendEmail and System.Net.Mail are not allowed in sandboxed solutions. Is there any way around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct according to the documentation [SPUtility.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460489.aspx) is not available in a sandbox solution.

The solution would be to create a [full trust proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798482.aspx) that can send the email for you.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote values to a SharePoint list, and then I'm going to create a workflow that sends emails when items are added to the list.